# upsample in a timeseries and interpolating data

Tags: pandas, interpolation, resampling

I need to perform an Upsample in a timeseries, and then to interpolate data and I would like to find the best way to do that. Timeseries has not constant interval. I show a DatFrame example and the result I'm looking. In the result example I'm interpolating just 1 row. It would be great to bea able to interpolate n rows.

```
data = {'time': ['08-12-2018 10:00:00','08-12-2018 10:01:00','08-12-2018 \
10:01:30','08-12-2018 10:03:00','08-12-2018 10:03:10'], 'value':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df
Out[42]: 
                 time  value
0 2018-08-12 10:00:00      1
1 2018-08-12 10:01:00      2
2 2018-08-12 10:01:30      3
3 2018-08-12 10:03:00      4
4 2018-08-12 10:03:10      5
```

Result

```
                 time  value
0 2018-08-12 10:00:00      1
1 2018-08-12 10:00:30      1.5
2 2018-08-12 10:01:00      2
3 2018-08-12 10:01:15      2.5
4 2018-08-12 10:01:30      3
5 2018-08-12 10:02:15      3.5
6 2018-08-12 10:03:00      4
7 2018-08-12 10:03:05      4.5
8 2018-08-12 10:03:10      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiple index, convert datetime to numeric - native numpy array in nanoseconds, so possible add new `NaN`s rows by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html). Last convert `time` column back to `datetime`s:

```
N = 2
df.index = df.index * N
df.time= df.time.astype(np.int64)
df1 = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max() + 1)).interpolate()
df1.time=pd.to_datetime(df1.time)
print (df1)
                 time  value
0 2018-08-12 10:00:00    1.0
1 2018-08-12 10:00:30    1.5
2 2018-08-12 10:01:00    2.0
3 2018-08-12 10:01:15    2.5
4 2018-08-12 10:01:30    3.0
5 2018-08-12 10:02:15    3.5
6 2018-08-12 10:03:00    4.0
7 2018-08-12 10:03:05    4.5
8 2018-08-12 10:03:10    5.0
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.